# Selenium GRID deployment on Docker - which containers?

Tags: selenium, docker, internet-explorer, selenium-grid

I'm planning a Selenium GRID deployment on Docker. Can you help me answer some basic questions:

1. For the ***Selenium Hub*** container - I assume I need a container with Linux + Java runtime + Selenium Server JAR. Would a Windows container also work in this case?
2. For the ***grid nodes***, I assume I would need a Linux container + Chrome/ Firefox installed. For this to work does Chrome/ Firefox need to be headless?
3. For testing ***Internet Explorer*** or Edge, in a container, I would need a Windows container, right? But in a Windows container there is no Windows GUI... Does that mean I will need to use a VM and not a container?

Comment: selenium project provides fully configured containers for running grid hub and nodes

Comment: docker already package all in `https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium`.
for you describe, you still need put `chromedriver` in you OS somewhere

Comment: Yes, I've seen they already provide configured containers. I was just wondering if my assumptions were correct: whether I need containers with the configuration I specified above.